# Manually deleted current kernel headers package

Tags: kernel

I manually deleted the `linux-headers` package in `/usr/src/` by mistake. I can't get them back as the current kernel image is up-to date, so:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

doesn't work.

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: It gives back an error saying 'Invalid Operation reinstall'

Comment: @VineethSoma - try the revised solution.